# 3D ScrollView Help - Like music app

Tags: animation, 3d, uiscrollview

I am trying to make a 3D "Wheel" type thing. It will have 3 or 5 items on the page.

The top or focused one will be filling up most of the page, then there will be two zoomed out more and on the sides.

I know it will have to use a scrollView and some animation.

A great example of what I want to do is the music app in lanscape. [image]
[image]

How would I go around doing this?
Thanks is advanced,
 Alex

Comment: Have a look at this open source library. https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

Comment: @AlexLittlejohn Post that as an answer, get credit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this open source library. 
http://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this androidlibraries    http://listview.android-libraries.com/